# How long it will take to work in selenium rc including all type of process

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

How to configure Selenium RC?

How long it will take to configure?

How to work with Selenium RC?

What are the pre-requisties for working Selenium RC?

Answer (score 1):

configuring Selenium RC is calling it from a shell (Bash or Command Prompt) with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar` and then use your favourite language that is supported to create your tests. It is that simple.